# Dropdown Menu Won't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I slapped together some code and made a slide-y horizontal dropdown navbar, but the problem is that while it works in chrome and firefox, it won't work in internet explorer. Here's the code. I really appreciate all the help, everyone.

```js
$(function () {

  $(".item").on("click", function () {
    $(this)
      .next().toggleClass("active");
  });
  
  $("#body").css("min-height", "100%");

  
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 150%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-left:-15px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;

}
.item{
  font-size: calc(8px + .8vw);
  width:9%; 
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 3px solid #333333;
  font: monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #B9E3C6;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;

}

.info{
  font-size: calc(8px + .8vw);
  float: left;
  width:0%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #DEF9E3;
  visibility: hidden;
  font: monospace;
  background-color: gr;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: width ease-out .3s, visibility ease-out .3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;

}
.info.active{
  visibility: visible;
  width:12%;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;

  
}
.nitem{
  font-size: calc(8px + .8vw);
  width:9%; 
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 3px solid #333333;
  font: monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #B9E3C6;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <section>
   <div class="item"> about <span style='font-size: 1.3vw;'>►</span></div>
   <div class="info">lab  |  research</div>

   <div class="item"> people <span style='font-size: 1.3vw;'>►</span></div>
   <div class="info">current  |  alumni</div>
   
   <div class="nitem"> publications</div>
  
   <div class="nitem"> contact</div>
   </section>
 </div>
  
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you having trouble with? It works for me in 11 and EDGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with Internet Explorer, you need to put some constraints on it or it's going to end in heartbreak.

Use a proper doctype such as (though there are many doctypes):
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Then right below the doctype add the following line:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />

The above meta tag ensures IE loads the same version for every user, regardless of what webbrowser they actually have installed. I like to load IE10.

You should also check out http://jqueryui.com/ and see what they have to offer in terms of cool doodads to help you present information with.

Hope that helps.